# How do you reference a sql script (not procedure) in a Script.PostDeployment.sql in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, sqlcmd, database-project

**How to get the path to a script (not procedure) in Azure DevOps build?**

I'm trying to get the path to either my solution or project file to use in **Visual Studio database project PostDeployment**.

**Works locally**

In the **Script.PostDeployment.sql** file in a Visual Studio Database project I have the following code

```
SELECT @solutionDir = REPLACE('$(SolutionPath)','MySoulution.sln','');
SET @File = @solutionDir + 'myScript.sql'
-- and here I can use the @File
```

When I do a **local publish/or build** I can use the variable/macro $(SolutionPath) where I get the full local path to the solution.

With that I can point to the script I need to access.

#### Fails in AzureDevops

But Azure DevOps build doesn´t have the $(SolutionPath) macro and I get the **following error**

```
SCRIPT.POSTDEPLOYMENT.SQL(17,32,17,32): Build error SQL72008: Variable SolutionPath is not defined.
```

So I need a way (in AzureDevops) **in the build step** to get the path to the scripts.

#### What I have tried

1. I have tried all kinds of macros that just don't seem to work.
2. I have tried to work with [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)
3. I tried to use [SqlCommandVariableOverride](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gertd/2009/06/21/assigning-msbuild-properties-to-sqlcmd-variables/) but it seems to have gone missing from the database project some time ago.

### Questions

1. How can I add $(SolutionPath) (or something else) to my build step so this works both locally and in Azure DevOps build?
2. Is there another way to get a solution or project url to the postdeployment SQLCMD file?
3. Is [MSBuild Extension Pack](https://github.com/mikefourie/MSBuildExtensionPack/wiki/USING-THE-SAMPLES) something I should look at? I will if it is my only option.

#### p.s

I also [created a ticket for this in Azure Pipelines Tasks](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11469) since they don´t seem to be that active in answering and I can't wait.

#### e.s

I asked the same question at [developercommunity.visualstudio.com](http://How%20do%20you%20reference%20a%20sql%20script%20(not%20procedure)%20in%20a%20Script.PostDeployment.sql%20in%20Azure%20DevOps?). Lets hope somebody there will be able to answer the question. If so I will update this question with an answer.

Comment: You can use this task in your build pipeline to run post-deployment scripts that uses SQLCMD variables - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DrJohnExtensions.RunSqlCmdScripts

Comment: I'm not sure that works with my Script.PostDeployment.sq script. Your build task would run after that one but the database project has at that time already created a dacpac file if it had not hit the problem of not finding that $(SolutionPath) variable. I think need another solution...

Answer (score 0):

So first double check that your build is publishing the artifacts.  there should be a blue button in the top right corner of your build that says "artifacts".  To have access to the artifact you need to do an archive task after you do the build and point it at

```
$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

Then I would recommend not using SQL to make direct references to the filesystem for the build server.  If this is absolutely necessary then you should use environment variables.

I would recommend setting up a release pipeline for deployment of the SQL script.  Release pipelines are really designed for deployment, whereas builds are for compilation.

To configure the release, point it to the artifact and then you can access that artifact by `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip` then run whatever commands you want to do to process that.

Comment: Hi thanks but not what I'm looking for. What I'm dealing with is a *.dacpack that gets created on solution build, containing the postdeploy.sql file I need. The Script.PostDeployment.sql file needs to have something in it at BUILD TIME to be able to set these paths. But thanks for trying...

Comment: Ok even thought your answer is not what I'm looking for this got me thinking that I could maybe change the *.dacpack to zip and then manipulate the content of the file.

 At this stage I have no idea how that will pan out. I would then have to 
1.u-zip the *.dacpac. 
2. change the paths to the scripts to an absolute path from the build. 
3. re-zip the file(s) back into the dackpack. There just has to be another way

Comment: @Sturla there is an execute SQL script free DevOps add-in https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=automagically.ExecuteSqlScript  If that doesn't get you where you're going you also have access to run powershell scripts from the release agent or directly from DevOps.  If you're using Azure SQL its even easier because you can deploy a DACPAC directly from the "azure SQL deployment" task.